# How to attach an onclick listener to Android Studio's navigation drawer activity?

Tags: android, android-studio, navigation-drawer

I am attempted to create an application in Android studio that has a navigation drawer.

I am using Android Studio (beta)0.8.14.  In this version, there is a navigation drawer activity.  I been able to set the labels for my navigation drawer menu using this piece of code and the corresponding values in my strings file

```
public void onSectionAttached(int number) {
        switch (number) {
            case 1:
                mTitle = getString(R.string.login);
                break;
            case 2:
                mTitle = getString(R.string.sign_up);
                break;
            case 3:
                mTitle = getString(R.string.view_map);
                break;
            case 4:
                mTitle = getString(R.string.about);
                break;
            case 5:
                mTitle = getString(R.string.version);
        }
    }
```

It looks really nice, but I can't figure out how to add onClickListeners for each of the items.

I've also added this in my NavigationDrawerFragment.java (which was automatically created by Android Studio):

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        mDrawerListView = (ListView) inflater.inflate(
                R.layout.fragment_navigation_drawer, container, false);
        mDrawerListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                selectItem(position);
            }
        });
        mDrawerListView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                getActionBar().getThemedContext(),
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_1,
                android.R.id.text1,
                new String[]{
                        getString(R.string.login),
                        getString(R.string.sign_up),
                        getString(R.string.view_map),
                        getString(R.string.about),
                        getString(R.string.version),
                }));
        mDrawerListView.setItemChecked(mCurrentSelectedPosition, true);
        return mDrawerListView;
    }
```

I would like to launch a different activity for each of the list items but I can't understand how and unfortunately I can't seem to find a tutorial that uses Android Studio's built-in navigation drawer activity.

Also, is it possible to have this navigation drawer available on all of my activities?  Do I need to create a new navigation drawer fragment every time I create a new activity?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea of having a navigation drawer is to use fragment. It wouldn't be very efficient to launch a new activity whenever you click an item in your navigation drawer.

In your `selectItem(position)` method you could execute some code for creating a new fragment for list item in your navigation drawer. Each navigation item should be a different fragment then just use a fragment transaction to add it to the container view of the main activity.

As a simple example of what the method may look like:

```
private void selectItem(int position) {

FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();

        switch(position) {
            //fragment for position 0
            case 0:
                fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.container, new Fragment0())
                        .commit();
                break;
            //fragment for postion 1
            case 1:
                fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.container, new Fragment1())
                        .commit(); 
                break;
            //fragment for position 2
            case 2:
                fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.container, new Fragment2())
                        .commit(); 
                break;             
            default:
                break;
        }
}
```

This may not be exactly what you want but it is an option for what you're trying to accomplish.

As a note in order for onSectionAttached() to work, all your framents will have to call that to pass their title to the main activity.

See [this](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html) link for more info.

Comment: Thank you,  I've had a hard time trying to understand fragments.  They make much more sense now.  It's been hard to understand why I would use a fragment vs an activity when they look so similar.

Answer (score 0):

In order to put onclicklisteners on your navigation drawer, just put an intent below the line of code where you are changing the title bar i.e. in the switch case block
e.g.

```
case 1:    
mTitle = getString(R.string.login);    
Intent transfer = new Intent(HomeFragment.this,NextActivity.class);    
startActivity(transfer);
```

This will do it for you.